# ssh - prompting for password even for non encryption key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I wanted to do the ssh from my local machine to a remote server.

I tried with this: `ssh user@server`

[image]

I copied my private keys into `.ssh/id_dsa` into my user home directory, and see my private key is not encrypted as mentioned.

[image]

Please let me know how I can remove this prompt at the time of ssh to the remote.

FYI, when I tried to log in with it, it works without any prompt as mentioned.

`ssh -i location-of-pkey user@server`

Note - I already setup the remote server with my public key already.

Comment: What was the working directory when you invoked `cat .ssh/id_dsa`? It's not clear it was `/home/mobaxterm`. Was it? Is `location-of-pkey` `/home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa`?

Comment: correct I was using mobaexterm as a client, and my root directory is "/home/mobaxterm" only whereas I copied my private key into its .ssh directory only. please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski please correct me if I am out something wrong here!!

Comment: If I knew what's wrong, I would have already written an answer. I have some experience with SSH, but not much with encrypted keys nor MobaXterm. The best I can suggest at the moment is this link: [*What should I do if no one answers my question?*](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: thanks, Kamil I will make the question more clear and concise.

Comment: are permissions correct? private key 600, public 644, .ssh directory 700, owner is you. Is content of .ssh/authorized_keys on server have single lines for keys? (inevitably, if you copy/paste you get it wrong). Of course if authorized keys file corrupt like that no one can probably log in except via console.